# How to use recursion in python to add up values assigned to letters/numbers in a string?

Tags: python

I am new to python and still dont have a full understanding of how recursion works. I am writing a program that goes through a string and adds up the values assigned to it.

- a letter would be given 1 point
- a number would be the amount of points the number actually is
- a space would be zero points

e.g print(count_function("Cows 16") would give an amount of 11

How can I go about doing this?

```
def str_score (s): 
if ((s[len(s) - 1].isalpha())): 
    return 1
if ((s[len(s) - 1].isdigit())):
    return int(s[len(s) - 1])
if (' ' in s):
    return 0
```

This is what I had going but not sure how to do the recursion part

Comment: A recursion does not make any sense for a problem involving a sequence. Can I give an answer which explains recursion with a more suitable example?

Comment: Yes that would be great! But I also want to be able to solve this question if you can help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I like to visualize recursion like the movie inception. We can call the method from inside a method. From inside a dream we can go into another dream. Inside each of these dreams we can do operations, when we are done we can wake back up and provide the result to the upper layer. So first we need to determine what is going to be our end case when we want to start unraveling our dream. In this case its when we have reached the last character in our string. If we are not there, then we will go one dream deeper.

```
def calc_score(n):
    # Calculate the score for the first element in the string
    score = 0
    if n[0] == ' ': score = 0
    elif not n[0].isdigit(): score = 1
    else: score = int(n[0])

    # If the current dream only has a single element
    # return the score
    if len(n) == 1: return score

    # If there are more than one element in the
    # string still, then go into another dream layer
    # with the string without the first character.
    else:
        score += calc_score(n[1::])
        return score

n = "Cows 16"
calc_score(n)
```

> 11

---

We can see that this is not an ideal case scenario where we would want to use recursion. We do not need to go into layers of dreams continuously because we know the sequence across which we will apply our algorithm, thus a for loop would be optimal for this.

```
def calc_score(n):
    score = 0
    for i in n:
        if i == ' ': continue
        elif not i.isdigit(): score += 1
        else: score += int(i)
    return score

n = "Cows 16"
calc_score(n)
```

> 11

Answer (score 0):

This is a one-liner that will accomplish what you are describing through the use of iterable comprehension, assuming that special characters have a score of 0 similar to whitespace.  This function will create an array containing a score for each character in the string, then the sum of these scored is calculated and returned.

```
def str_score(s):
    return sum([int(x) if x.isdigit() else 1 if x.isalpha() else 0 for x in s])

print(str_score('Cows 16'))
>>> 11
```

If you want special characters to have a value of 1, such as letters then the following function would achieve this functionality.

```
def str_score(s):
    return sum([int(x) if x.isdigit() else 1 for x in s.replace(' ', '')])
```

In the second function I have removed all spaces from the string since they have no value.

Answer (score -1):

There are other non alpha-numeric values that could be passed besides a space, so we should ONLY check for numbers or letters, since these are the only items which can receive a value, hence ignoring anything else passed in the string.

The function in the below code will check each value in a string of any length and return the associated amount as per the rules you stipulated.

```
def str_score(s):

    count = 0 

    for letter in s:
        if unicode(letter, "utf-8").isalpha():
            count += 1
        if unicode(letter, "utf-8").isnumeric():
            count += int(letter)

    return count

s = raw_input("Enter string: ")

count = str_score(s)

print count
```

Note: This will also deal with the case where len(s) == 0

Comment: The question explicitly asked for a recursive solution